# How do you say “Ours is a bond which cannot be cut.” in French?

Tags: traduction

Scenario

Younger brother: I can’t believe you’re leaving. When will I see you?

Elder brother: Often. Ours is a bond which cannot be cut.

How do you say “Ours is a bond which cannot be cut.” in French?

I want to say the answer is « Le nôtre est un lien qu’on ne peut pas couper. » but the fact that it’s close to the literal translation makes me unsure.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Que désigne *Le nôtre* ?

Comment: @XouDo *Le nôtre* renvoie à "un lien" ("notre lien"), mais cette construction ne fonctionne pas en français.

Comment: "Notre lien ne peut être coupé" is the correct word order for French for this sentence.

Comment: Ours is a bond that cannot be **broken**. To break a bond between two people. **Le lien entre nous ne peut pas être rompu**.

Comment: So we cannot refer to « notre lien » with the possessive pronouns « le nôtre »?

Comment: Of course you can. There are many ways to say this. Notre lien ne peut pas être rompu.

Comment: @Lambie So « Le nôtre est un lien qu’on ne peut ps pas couper/rompre. » is okay?

Comment: I am not the person to ask really but for me that sounds like the English one that starts with "Ours is a bond", which, by the way, is poetic in English. The reversal is poetic.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your help!

Comment: DeepL: Nous sommes unis par un lien qui ne peut être rompu.

Comment: Uniquement pour reproduire le tour, peut-être _ce lien qui est le nôtre..._.

Comment: @Amessihel Deepl is not a person. Just a machine. Nous sommes unis would be: We are united by a bond.

Comment: @Lambie, le résultat de DeepL est une piste. Pour la traduction elle-même, tout dépend où l'on souhaite placer le curseur entre littéralité et naturel.

Answer (score 13):

On peut dire :

> Nos liens sont indéfectibles.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135947/discussion-on-answer-by-pirela-how-do-you-say-ours-is-a-bond-which-cannot-be-cu).